# Strange Variable Scope Tensor names

Tags: python, tensorflow

I store my placeholder variables in the scope called **"inputs."** After training and saving a model, I try to reload it and evaluate it on test data. However, I can't make sense of how to reconstruct the feed_dict. I'm noticing I'm getting multiple "input" scopes, labeled **"input_#."** I noticed that when I run

```
graph = tf.get_default_graph()
    e1 = graph.get_tensor_by_name("inputs/e1:0")
    e2 = graph.get_tensor_by_name("inputs/e2:0")
    rel = graph.get_tensor_by_name("inputs/rel:0")
    y = graph.get_tensor_by_name("inputs/y:0")
```

I get an error. Placeholders e1, e2 are recognized but y is not:

> KeyError: "The name 'inputs/y:0' refers to a Tensor which does not
>   exist. The operation, 'inputs/y', does not exist in the graph."

My questions are: why am I not able to load placeholder y, why does it not appear in the variable scope "input," and why are there other "input" scopes. Below are examples of my code and outputs. Thanks for looking!

My Model:

```
with open('./data/generated.data/initialized.vectors-normalized', 'r') as f:
    vecs = pickle.load(f)

k = 3
d = 100
r = 11
lamb = 0.0001
lr = 0.01
words = 26770 # number of words in corpus, we add one row to it to get zero value

with tf.name_scope('inputs'):
    e1 = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[None, 10], name='e1')
    rel = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[None, 1], name='rel')
    e2 = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[None, 10], name='e2')
    y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None], name='y')

with tf.name_scope('parameters'):

    # initialization process for E, maintain e[0,:] = 0 vector for dummy variable c
    glove_rows = tf.constant(vecs, dtype='float32')
    E_init = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([words - vecs.shape[0] + 1,d], -0.001, 0.001))
    E = tf.concat([glove_rows, E_init], 0, name='E')
    #E =  E_init #tf.scatter_update(E_init, [0], [[0 for i in range(d)]])

    W = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([r, d*d*k], -1/(d**.5), 1/(d**.5)), name='W')
    V = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([r, 2*d*k], 0,1), name='R')
    B = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([r, k]), name='B')
    U = tf.Variable(tf.ones([r, k]), name='U')
    Bias = tf.Variable(tf.ones([r, 1]), name='Bias')

with tf.name_scope('equation'):

    # E1 Calc
    e1_words = e1[:,:9]
    e1_wordcount = tf.to_float(e1[:,9:], name = 'e1_wordcount')

    E1_entity_wordvecs = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(E, e1_words, name = 'E1_entity_wordvecs')
    E1_unscaled_entvecs = tf.reduce_sum(E1_entity_wordvecs, axis = 1, name = 'E1_unscaled_entvecs')
    E1 = tf.divide(E1_unscaled_entvecs, e1_wordcount, name = 'E1')

    ## 3 terms in parenthesis score function  
    #
    # E2 Calculation
    e2_words = e2[:,:9]
    e2_wordcount = tf.to_float(e2[:,9:], name = 'e2_wordcount')

    E2_entity_wordvecs = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(E, e2_words, name = 'E2_entity_wordvecs')
    E2_unscaled_entvecs = tf.reduce_sum(E2_entity_wordvecs, axis = 1, name = 'E2_unscaled_entvecs')
    E2 = tf.divide(E2_unscaled_entvecs, e2_wordcount, name = 'E2')

    # Term1 Calculation
    Wr = tf.reshape(tf.nn.embedding_lookup(W, rel), [-1,d,d,k], name = 'Wr')
    Term1 = tf.einsum('ij,ijmk,im->ik', E1, Wr, E2)

    # Term2 Calculation
    Vr = tf.reshape(tf.nn.embedding_lookup(V, rel), [-1,2*d,k], name = 'Vr')
    E1E2 = tf.concat([E1, E2], axis=1, name = 'E1E2')
    Term2 = tf.einsum('ijk,ij->ik', Vr, E1E2)

    # Term3 Calculation
    Br = tf.squeeze(tf.nn.embedding_lookup(B, rel),[1], name= 'Br')
    Term3 = Br

    # Score, a.k.a F, Calculation
    Ur = tf.squeeze(tf.nn.embedding_lookup(U, rel),[1], name= 'Ur')
    Biasr = tf.squeeze(tf.nn.embedding_lookup(Bias, rel),[1], name= 'Biasr')
    Tanh = tf.tanh(tf.add_n([Term1, Term2, Term3], name = 'Tanh'))
    F = tf.einsum('ij,ij->i', Ur, Tanh) + Biasr

with tf.name_scope('loss'):

    with tf.name_scope('cross_entropy_term'):

        compare_matrix = tf.maximum(1 - F * y, 0)
        Sum = tf.reduce_sum(compare_matrix)

    with tf.name_scope('regularization_term'):

        E_flat = tf.reshape(E, [-1])
        W_flat = tf.reshape(W, [-1])
        V_flat = tf.reshape(V, [-1])
        B_flat = tf.reshape(B, [-1])
        U_flat = tf.reshape(U, [-1])
        Params = tf.concat([E_flat, W_flat, V_flat, B_flat, U_flat], axis = 0)
        Reg = lamb * tf.norm(Params, ord=2, name='Reg')

    loss = tf.add(Sum, Reg, name = 'loss')

with tf.name_scope('optimizer'):
    train_step = tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(lr).minimize(loss)
```

After training and reloading, Output from

```
for i in tf.get_default_graph().get_operations():
    if i.name[:6] == 'input'
         print i.name
```

is shown below:

```
inputs/e1
inputs/rel
inputs/e2
inputs_1/e1
inputs_1/rel
inputs_1/e2
inputs_2/e1
inputs_2/rel
inputs_2/e2
inputs_3/e1
inputs_3/rel
inputs_3/e2
inputs_4/e1
inputs_4/rel
inputs_4/e2
inputs_5/e1
inputs_5/rel
inputs_5/e2
inputs_5/y
inputs_6/e1
inputs_6/rel
inputs_6/e2
inputs_6/y
inputs_7/e1
inputs_7/rel
inputs_7/e2
inputs_7/y
inputs_8/e1
inputs_8/rel
inputs_8/e2
inputs_8/y
inputs_9/e1
inputs_9/rel
inputs_9/e2
inputs_9/y
inputs_10/e1
inputs_10/rel
inputs_10/e2
inputs_10/y
inputs_11/e1
inputs_11/rel
inputs_11/e2
inputs_11/y
inputs/e1_1
inputs/rel_1
inputs/e2_1
inputs_1/e1_1
inputs_1/rel_1
inputs_1/e2_1
inputs_2/e1_1
inputs_2/rel_1
inputs_2/e2_1
inputs_3/e1_1
inputs_3/rel_1
inputs_3/e2_1
inputs_4/e1_1
inputs_4/rel_1
inputs_4/e2_1
inputs_5/e1_1
inputs_5/rel_1
inputs_5/e2_1
inputs_5/y_1
inputs_6/e1_1
inputs_6/rel_1
inputs_6/e2_1
inputs_6/y_1
inputs_7/e1_1
inputs_7/rel_1
inputs_7/e2_1
inputs_7/y_1
inputs_8/e1_1
inputs_8/rel_1
inputs_8/e2_1
inputs_8/y_1
inputs_9/e1_1
inputs_9/rel_1
inputs_9/e2_1
inputs_9/y_1
inputs_10/e1_1
inputs_10/rel_1
inputs_10/e2_1
inputs_10/y_1
inputs_11/e1_1
inputs_11/rel_1
inputs_11/e2_1
inputs_11/y_1
inputs/e1_2
inputs/rel_2
inputs/e2_2
inputs_1/e1_2
inputs_1/rel_2
inputs_1/e2_2
inputs_2/e1_2
inputs_2/rel_2
inputs_2/e2_2
inputs_3/e1_2
inputs_3/rel_2
inputs_3/e2_2
inputs_4/e1_2
inputs_4/rel_2
inputs_4/e2_2
inputs_5/e1_2
inputs_5/rel_2
inputs_5/e2_2
inputs_5/y_2
inputs_6/e1_2
inputs_6/rel_2
inputs_6/e2_2
inputs_6/y_2
inputs_7/e1_2
inputs_7/rel_2
inputs_7/e2_2
inputs_7/y_2
inputs_8/e1_2
inputs_8/rel_2
inputs_8/e2_2
inputs_8/y_2
inputs_9/e1_2
inputs_9/rel_2
inputs_9/e2_2
inputs_9/y_2
inputs_10/e1_2
inputs_10/rel_2
inputs_10/e2_2
inputs_10/y_2
inputs_11/e1_2
inputs_11/rel_2
inputs_11/e2_2
inputs_11/y_2
```

Comment: When you get into a `name_scope` with a name that already exists, it will automatically append an underscore and a numeric suffix to make a new one. Most likely, you are somehow running the block `with tf.name_scope('inputs')` several times.

Comment: @jdehesa that makes some sense. Perhaps as I was building and testing the graph progressively, Tensorflow did not over-write the tensors I redefined? If a graph is edited, does Tensorflow not delete tensors whose definitions change?

Comment: Once a node is added to a graph, it's there forever. You can create a new empty graph, or replace the default graph with a new one by calling `tf.reset_default_graph()`, but there is no such thing as "overwriting" an operator or tensor in TensorFlow. You can either create new ones or use the ones you already have. The Python variables (`e1`, etc.) will be bound to their latest assignment, but the older nodes will be there (you can see them with `tf.get_default_graph().get_operations()`, if you are using the default graph).

Comment: @jdehesa, I think then that my progressive building process without resetting the graph must have caused this issue. Thank you for your help. When building graphs, I will now use tf.reset_default_graph() before each sussessive build  change. I wonder if this is listed as a best practice on the tensorflow website

Comment: Well, maybe a more conventional approach would be to create a new graph each time, e.g. `g = tf.Graph()`, and then call your code from within a `with g.as_default():` block, but in the end I think it's equivalent.